# Funcion en PHP para remplazar palabras

Tags: php, function

Me gustaria ver si me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente, Me gustaria saber si es posible hacer una funcion en PHP para remplazar algunas palabras. Estoy usando `str_replace` de la siguiente manera:

```
$mensaje = "Hola!";
$mensaje = str_replace($mensaje, "Hola!", "Buen dia, Vuelve pronto");
```

con esto me obtengo esto:

> Buen dia, Vuelve pronto

Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para remplazar varios `$mensaje` con diferente resultado. Aquí algo de lo que busco.

```
$mensaje1 = "Hola!"; 
$mensaje2 = "Buen dia!";
$mensaje3 = "Buena tarde!";
$mensaje4 = "Buena Noche";
$mensaje5 = "Cuidado con el coco!";
```

y la salida fuera:

```
$mensaje1 = "Adios!";
$mensaje2 = "que te vaya bien!";
$mensaje3 = "Cuidado con el perro!";
$mensaje4 = "Ahi espantan!";
$mensaje5 = "Uyy! Qué miedo!";
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder remplazar los contenidos, por cada mensaje por separado. Lo puedes hacer pasando cada mensaje a ***array*** y luego ejecutándolo dentro de un ciclo te dejo un ejemplo espero que te sea de utilidad:

```
$array1 = array("Hola!","Buen dia!","Buena tarde!","Buena Noche","Cuidado con el coco!");
    $array2 = array("Adios!","que te vaya bien!","Cuidado con el perro!","Ahi espantan!","Uyy! Qué miedo!");

    for($i = 0; $i< count($array1);$i++){
        echo str_replace($array1[$i], $array1[$i],$array2[$i])."<br />";
    }
```

> Para mostrar uno solo a la vez

Si quieres, que se te muestre uno solo a la vez solo tienes que colocar el valor de **$i** fijo es decir si lo que quieres es la posición cero del ***array*** solo tienes que fijar el valor de **$i = 0** y así sucesivamente para el valor que quieras mostrar te dejo el ejemplo:

```
$array1 = array("Hola!","Buen dia!","Buena tarde!","Buena Noche","Cuidado con el coco!");
$array2 = array("Adios!","que te vaya bien!","Cuidado con el perro!","Ahi espantan!","Uyy! Qué miedo!");
 $i = 0;   
 echo str_replace($array1[$i], $array1[$i],$array2[$i]);
```

Comment: Me interesa mucho, pero al final me muestra todos los elementos, `Adiós! que te vaya bien! Cuidado con el perro! Ahi espantan! Uyy! Qué miedo!`, cómo podría mostrar solo uno dependiendo del caso?

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Te hice la modificación del código para que solo lo muestre una sola vez cualquier cosa no dudes en consultarme

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido de mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Como una función y validando que le pasen un String a la misma y que exista la variable,ademas de pasar todo a minúsculas para verificar mejor las coincidencias,un saludo y mucha suerte!.
PD: asi para PHP7 ,si quieres que funcione en PHP5 quitale "string" en la funcion remplazar.

```
<?php
    function remplazar(string $mensaje)
    {
        $array=array(
            "hola"=>"Adios!", 
            "buen dia"=>"Que te vaya bien!",
            "buenas tardes"=>"Cuidado con el perro"
        );
        $mensaje=strtolower($mensaje);
        if( isset($array[$mensaje]) )
        {
            return $array[$mensaje];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //$mensaje="hola";
    $mensaje="HolA";
    if(isset($mensaje) && is_string($mensaje))
    {
        $resultado=remplazar($mensaje);
        if(!$resultado)
        {
            echo "Error no se encuentra mensaje en array";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $resultado;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ingrese un mensaje valido de tipo string";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, me intereso mucho esta respuesta, Realmente esta bien explicada y me ayudara en un futuro. Gracias! @Andres Paiva